# SDC constraints for source clock and derived clock

Tags: synthesis, vlsi, constraints, cdc, sdc

There are two clocks in the system, clk2 is derived from clk1 with a 180-degree phase shift. There is 1-bit data from clk1 to clk2.

I know this is a kind of asynchronous scenario and the traditional method is the use of 2 FFs or an asynchronous FIFO to synchronize the data. However, since these two clocks have a fixed phase difference, so is it possible to synchronize the data **JUST** with SDC constraints? If it is possible, how to set the SDC?

[image: source clock and derived clock]

Answer (score 2):

Since we know the phase relation, those clocks are synchronous. The only thing we need to do is telling this relation to the synthesis/STA tool.

```
create_generated_clock -source clk1 -edges {2 3 4} -combinational [get_pins pll/clk2]
```

I would use the `-edges` option to define the phase. The following waveform explains the edges. Basically `clk2` rises at the 2nd edge of `clk1`, falls at the 3rd edge and rises again at the 4th edge.

```
edge    1    2    3    4    5    6
         ____      ____      ____
        |    |    |    |    |    |
clk1    |    |    |    |    |    |
    ____|    |____|    |____|    |____
              ____      ____      ____
             |    |    |    |    |    |
clk2         |    |    |    |    |    |
         ____|    |____|    |____|    |____
```

The 1-bit data has a half clock cycle to arrive the target FF. By the help of our constraint, the tool will perform setup/hold timing checks accordingly.

Comment: But I think if we constraint clk1, clk2 constraints will be auto generated cz its from PLL.

Comment: @MituRaj Some tools in some cases propagate clk1 as it is. I wouldn't rely on the tool.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether this -invert flag would work.

create_generated_clock -source clk1 -invert -combinational [get_pins pll/clk2]